# Pushdown Automata (PDA)

Tags: pushdown-automaton

I'm trying to write a pda pushdown automata that accept a^2n b^n, n>0
but I'm not sure if the last part is correct

```
(p0, a, z0) = (p0, az0)
(p0, a, a) = (p0, aa)
(p0, b, a) = (p1, λ)
(p1, λ, b) = (p2, λ)   <=
(p2, 0, b) = (p1, λ)  <=
(p2, λ, z0) = (p3, λ)  <=
```

Comment: Why do you go back to p0? That doesn't seem right.

Comment: @harold ya...i'm following an example, what about now?

Comment: Still not quite (not enough opportunities to push 1's). Did you draw it? That might help

Comment: @harold now? I was only taught with some similar examples in these format...I'm not sure how to draw it

Comment: Well now it can't get into p1, getting closer though

Comment: Very close, as far as I can see it just needs a rule from p2 back to p1 to read some more 0's

Comment: Looks good, personally I'd be consistent and use `a` and `b` for the input symbols but that's a minor thing

Answer (score 0):

As far as your answer is concerned, in your first two steps you are pushing a's in only one step.  With the current design the machine would accept aaabb which is not in the form a^2nb^n. So it's better to divide it in two states separately. According to me the right answer might be something like:

1. (p0, a, z0) = (p0, az0)
2. (p0, a, a) = (p1, aa)
3. (p1, a, a) = (p0, aa)
4. (p1, b, a) = (p2, λ)

Answer (score 0):

Deterministic push down automata for a^2nb^n n>=0 
Bypass altetnate a's and push rest of a's

[image: flipchart capture]

Comment: This PDA will also work for a^(2n - 1)b^n. To correct this the first state and can bypass a's and the in the second one you can push a's.

Answer (score 0):

`q0` is initial state and `qf` is final is state; `^` is for null:

```
Q(q0,a,z)=Q(q1,z)
Q(q0,a,a)=Q(q1,aa)
Q(q0,b,a)=Q(q0,^)
Q(q0,^,z)=Q(qf,z)
Q(q1,a,z)=Q(q2,az)
Q(q1,a,a)=Q(q2,a,a)
Q(q2,a,a)=Q(q0,az)
```